# Outputting dynamic text in clean columns

Tags: javascript, html-table

The program itself runs fine for all intents and purposes. However, my output is not quite as clean as I would like. I am using a number of `&nbsp` in each loop iteration to output a somewhat style column. I am wondering if there would be a better output method without using `&nbsp` or if perfecting the art of space guessing just comes with time?

[image: how the output looks as of now]

My function:

```
    function secret(){
    var month = prompt("Enter the month:");
    var dumplings = prompt("How many dumplings did Po eat?");

    var total = parseInt(dumplings);
    var test = false;

    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Month&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspNumber of Dumplings<br>";
    document.getElementById("decision").innerHTML += month.toUpperCase()+"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+dumplings+" dumplings<br>";
    do{
        var month = prompt("Enter another month or enter 'done' when finished:");

        if (month == "done"){
            test = true;
            break;
        }

        var dumplings = prompt("How many dumplings did Po eat?");
        total += parseInt(dumplings);
            document.getElementById("decision").innerHTML += month.toUpperCase()+"&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+dumplings+" dumplings<br>";
    }while (test != true)


    document.getElementById("phrase").innerHTML += "Po ate a total of "+total+" dumplings.";
}
```

Comment: There's much better ways than using `&nbsp;`. I'd suggest reading up on CSS and get more comfortable with HTML.

Comment: If you're trying to display a table, use `<table>`.

Comment: Using `&nbsp;` for layout is something we did in the early days of the web.  You should be using HTML tables, or CSS for layout.

Comment: I see what you mean with CSS. I am just not entirely sure how I would separate the "Month" and "Number of Dumplings" in the title id. The variables month and dumplings will be easier to manipulate I would imagine.

Comment: @RyanMann You can use `<span class="myClass"></span>`...

Answer (score 1):

When data is tabular, a table is the best choice. From there, CSS controls all styling. Don't ever use HTML elements for formatting (that's what we did 100 years ago when the web was new).

Also, there was a lot of redundancy in your code. Here's a cleaned up version:

```js
// Run the code when the document is ready
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Set up variables that function will work with
  var month = null;
  var dumplings = null;
  var total = null;
  var test = false;
  
  // Get references to the HTML elements that we'll need:
  var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");    
  var result = document.getElementById("result"); 
  
  // Begin loop
  do {
      
    month = prompt("Enter month or enter 'done' when finished:");
    if (month === "done"){
      test = true;
      break;
    }
    
    // We will want to work with this answer as a number, so we'll parse the
    // integer out of it (using base 10).
    dumplings = parseInt(prompt("How many dumplings did Po eat?"), 10);

    // Create a new row for the table
    var row = tbl.insertRow();
    
    // Create a new cell in that row at position 0
    var cell = row.insertCell(0);
    
    // Populate the cell (use textContent instead of innerHTML when no HTML will be used)
    cell.textContent =  month.toUpperCase();
    
    // Repeat for second cell in row
    cell = row.insertCell(1);
    cell.textContent =  dumplings;
      
    // Add dumpling count to the total
    total += dumplings;
    
  } while (!test)
  
  // Once we are out of the loop, remove the hidden class from the table (thus, showing it)
  tbl.classList.remove("hidden");

  // Update the result area with the total.
  result.textContent += "Po ate a total of " + total + " dumplings.";

});
```

```css
/* CSS allows us to query the document for elements and indicate how they should be presented */

/* Here's a class that indicates that anything using it should not be displayed.
   The HTML table has class="hidden" so that it starts off not shown.             */
.hidden { display:none; }

/* Give the table a background color */
table { background-color:aliceblue; }

/* Put some space around all 4 edges of each cell */
th, td { padding:3px; }
```

```html
<h1>Poe's Dumpling Log:</h1>
<table class="hidden" id="tbl">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Month</th>
       <th>Dumplings</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `document.write` is not the same thing as `innerHTML`
2. `&nbsp;` stands for "non-breaking space". It should only be used to solve some well-known problems with typography. For example, in French, you need a non-breaking space between a word and a question mark. Here it makes sense to use `&nbsp;`.
3. When you develop a website (even a static page), you should always distinguish the **content** (HTML), the **presentation** (CSS) and the **behavior** (JS).

Here you are trying to make some presentation with HTML. This is obviously wrong. You must use CSS. :)